# How to line up Tees when connecting brass fittings?

Tags: plumbing, fitting

I'm making a fire pit burner because the type I want is $1500+ and the materials amount to about $200 for diy. I need to make sure that when I tighten all the fittings that the fittings and pipes all lay on the same plane. The specific amount of torque that I've always been told to use is "good-n-tight" for brass fittings. When assembling this thing, do I hand tighten until snug and then tighten to the desired position? Or do I over tighten to the desired position? I plan on using yellow tape because the temp of the burner shouldn't exceed the temperature tolerance ptfe. The design is meant to be something like the "warming trends" cross fire inserts. I probably won't tape the jets.

Comment: Gas pressure at the burner is going to be less than a pound, I doubt that you will have any leaks even if just hand tight with often on the threads

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I just want to be super careful with this since it's propane. I'd be afraid it would settle on the pan and then ignite. I'm picturing hot lava rocks flying everywhere. I guess part of that is adequate venting too.

Comment: I guess spell check changed pfte to often, it did it again. Propane is heavier than air but dissipates quickly. Ever notice the amount that gets released when filling the tanks? Once regulated to a useable pressure and mixed with air in the burner assembly you will probably be fine even slightly more than snug , if you want to check it use a soap & water solution and look for bubbles